# how to find and replace user email in rails views?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need replace user email adress with some text, example `@user.email = test@test.com` but in views its look like xxxx@test.com
How can it be done?
Help please!
Thanks!
I'm use
Rails 4
ruby 2.0.0
devise 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new method in your `User` model called `protected_email` and use that to output the address to the view.

Something like this would work:

```
def protected_email
  self.email.gsub /[^@]*@/, 'xxx@'
end
```